# Receiving SwiftUI observed changes on the main thread

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Is there any way to tell SwiftUI to receive changes to an `@ObservedObject` property on the main thread?

I have a model object that manages a list of chat messages and users in a chat channel. The channel is fed by some websocket code that periodically calls methods like `addMessages()` or `usersJoinedAndLeft()` on my model. My model then does some housekeeping of user and message lists.

```swift
class ChatStream
    @Published var users: [Users]
    @Published var messages: [Message]
}
```

My SwiftUI  looks like

```swift
struct OverlayChatView : View {
    @ObservedObject public var stream: ChatStream
    var body: some View {
        …
            ForEach(self.stream.messages) { inMsg in
            }
        …
    }
}
```

This all works great. The problem came when my network code updated to make its calls on a different dispatch queue. Now the changes to `.users` and `.messages` happen on this queue, and SwiftUI tries to update on this queue.

The obvious fix is to wrap all my changes to `.users` and `.messages` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` calls. But that gets kind of messy, as all that housekeeping is done in-place, possibly updating `.users` and `.messages` several times before it finishes processing a set of incoming messages or user presence changes (in the end it keeps an ordered list of messages and a collection of present and departed users, with each message referencing its author, because users can come back, and their properties can change.)

So, I could change my code to work on temporary copies of these collections, and only set the published properties at the end of the processing in a dispatch async call. This would have the added benefit of coalescing a lot of those interim changes.

I could add a second `PassthroughSubject` and call `.send()` at the end, but this seems clunky and undoes the streamlined nature of SwiftUI, since I’d probably have to keep a separate copy of the state to update on the main thread.

What I’d love to do is something like

```swift
    @ObservedObject(receiveOn: DispatchQueue.main) var stream: ChatStream
```

or alternatively in my model, something like

```swift
class ChatStream {
    func add(messages: [Message]) {
        self.$users.suspend()
        self.$messages.suspend()
        …process messages…
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.$users.resume()
            self.$messages.resume()
        }
}
```

But it seems SwiftUI should probably just handle rebuilding the UI on the main thread for me, given that it requires it.

Comment: if you are using combine publishers to update your messages/usernames, you can use this modifier to swith to main Runloop https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/receive(on:options:)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reasoning around why it gets messy to use `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: Because every modification to the model generates a notification. My model takes care to update each user in a list, move them to a separate list if they've left, update the list of messages and sort them, etc. I do that all in-place. I have to do the whole processing on the main thread, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @Rick, "Because every modification to the model generates a notification" - that's not correct. An edit of a Published property does not each cause a rerender. rerenders are coalesced.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing. In particular, whether coalesced or not, they're not coming in on the main thread.

Comment: Can't comment on what you're seeing in your code - multiple synchronous changes should not cause multiple rerenders. But if you want to do a lot of heavy lifting while updating, then why not just remove the `@Published`, and instead do something like `willSet { DispatchQueue.main.async { self.objectWillChange.send() } }`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this, since you have publishers?

```
class ChatStream
    @Published var users: [Users]
    @Published var messages: [Message]
}

struct OverlayChatView : View {
    @ObservedObject public var stream: ChatStream
    var body: some View {
        …
            ForEach(self.stream.$messages.receive((on: DispatchQueue.main)) { inMsg in
            }
        …
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will work for `ForEach` but will for `.onReceive` if you can modify your code

```
.onReceive(self.observedObject.$publishedProperty.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main), perform: { newValue in
    ....
})
```

Answer (score 1):

#### View solution

If you don't mind adding some additional code to your views you may be able to observe the `objectWillChange` [Publisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/objectwillchange-2oa5v) of your `ObservableObject`, then update a `@State` property on your view on the main queue, e.g. something like:

```swift
struct ChatView: View {
    @ObservedObject var stream: ChatStream

    @State private var _refreshState: Bool = false 
    
    var body: some View {
        YourChatViewContent()
            .onReceive(stream.objectWillChange) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    _refreshState.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Since `_refreshState` changes on the main queue it *should* trigger a re-render of the view, which *should* use the new values of the `ChatStream` object, though this solution might result in multiple toggles of `_refreshState`, since `objectWillChange` will be triggered once for every state change in your `ObservableObject`, which could result in unnecessary renders.

You could then wrap the `onReceive` part in an extension function if you're re-using the same pattern in other views.

#### ObservableObject solution

Alternatively, in your `ObservableObject`, calling `self.objectWillChange.send()` on the main queue *should* also trigger an update of the view, e.g:

```swift
class ChatStream: ObservableObject {
    func add(messages: [Message]) {
        …process messages…
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

But then you might as well just set the values of your `@Published` properties on the main queue in the first place.

Comment: That's marginally better than adding `PassthroughSubjects`, but still clutters the view in a way I find unappealing. I submitted an enhancement request to Apple to make this easier.

Comment: The "ObservableObject solution" won't work because the changes in …process messages… will trigger the view update from the wrong queue.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to unpublish var `users` and `messages` and manually publish changes by calling `objectWillChange.send()` on the main queue when ready.

```
class ChatStream
    var users: [Users]
    var messages: [Message]
    func add(messages: [Message]) {
        …process messages…
    
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```